# tabindex goes in order if something missed in center then it goes to tabindex 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im having tabindex from tabindex="1" through tabindex="20", these are dynamically genreated. somethimes tabindex="16" wont be generated that time, while clicking from "15" it goes to "1", but i want it to go to "17", how can i achieve that?

```
<script>
        $(document).on("keypress", ".TabOnEnter" , function(e)
          {
            //Only do something when the user presses enter
            if( e.keyCode ==  13 )
            {
               var nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex+1)  + '"]');
               console.log( this , nextElement );
               if(nextElement.length )
                 nextElement.focus()
               else
                 $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();  
            }   
          });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script>
            $(document).on("keypress", ".TabOnEnter" , function(e)
              {
                //Only do something when the user presses enter
                if( e.keyCode ==  13 )
                {
                   var nextIndex = this.tabIndex + 1;
                   var nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + nextIndex  + '"]');
                   console.log( this , nextElement );

                   while(!nextElement.length){
                       nextIndex++;
                       if(nextIndex>20){
                           break;
                       }else{
                           nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + nextIndex + '"]');
                       }
                  }
                  nextElement.focus();       
                }   
              });   
    </script>
```

Comment: somewhat ok, but its not confirm that "16" only the missing index, it may be 16, 17, 18 (all the three or any two)

Answer (score 0):

The following will work with any number of inputs, in any tabindex order, and with any missing `tabindex`es (including tabindex=1).

If you're on the last tabindex, the input with the lowest tabindex is focused next.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.TabOnEnter' , function(e) {
  if(e.which===13) {
    var tabs= $('[tabindex]'),
        firstElement= tabs[0],
        nextElement,
        self= this;

    tabs.each(function() {
      if(this.tabIndex > self.tabIndex && 
         (!nextElement || this.tabIndex < nextElement.tabIndex)
        ) {
        nextElement= this;
      }
      if(this.tabIndex < firstElement.tabIndex) {
        firstElement= this;
      }
    });

    (nextElement || firstElement).focus();      
  }
});
```

Note that **[`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)** is recommended over `event.keyCode`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nwyegLj/)

Answer (score -1):

[According to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

"Avoid using tabindex values greater than 1. Doing so will make it difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and operate page content."

Just set tabindex to 0 for elements that need to be keyboard focusable and order your HTML elements in a way that makes logical sense for your content.